# MongoDB Aggregation by Name and Different Time Interval

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been looking for a solution for several days, and I can not get a result. Please, help me!

I have a data in MongoDB:

```
{ name: 'apple', date: 2018-01-04T10:00:00.000Z, price: 100 }
{ name: 'apple', date: 2018-01-04T10:01:00.000Z, price: 101 }
{ name: 'apple', date: 2018-01-04T10:02:00.000Z, price: 102 }
{ name: 'apple', date: 2018-01-04T10:03:00.000Z, price: 103 }
{ name: 'apple', date: 2018-01-04T10:04:00.000Z, price: 102 }
{ name: 'apple', date: 2018-01-04T10:05:00.000Z, price: 104 }

{ name: 'cherry', date: 2018-01-04T10:00:00.000Z, price: 53 }
{ name: 'cherry', date: 2018-01-04T10:01:00.000Z, price: 55 }
{ name: 'cherry', date: 2018-01-04T10:02:00.000Z, price: 51 }
{ name: 'cherry', date: 2018-01-04T10:03:00.000Z, price: 51 }
{ name: 'cherry', date: 2018-01-04T10:04:00.000Z, price: 50 }
{ name: 'cherry', date: 2018-01-04T10:05:00.000Z, price: 52 }

{ name: 'melon', date: 2018-01-04T10:00:00.000Z, price: 133 }
{ name: 'melon', date: 2018-01-04T10:01:00.000Z, price: 132 }
{ name: 'melon', date: 2018-01-04T10:02:00.000Z, price: 136 }
{ name: 'melon', date: 2018-01-04T10:03:00.000Z, price: 137 }
{ name: 'melon', date: 2018-01-04T10:04:00.000Z, price: 138 }
{ name: 'melon', date: 2018-01-04T10:05:00.000Z, price: 140 }
```

And i want to get this result by one query.

```
{name: 'apple', price_last: 104, price_1m_ago: 102, price_5m_ago: 100}
{name: 'cherry', price_last: 52, price_1m_ago: 50, price_5m_ago: 53}
{name: 'melon', price_last: 140, price_1m_ago: 138, price_5m_ago: 133}
```

I tried to use aggregation but I can not build a valid query in any way.

```
food.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            price_last: {$last:"$price"},
        }
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is guaranteed to contain one element per minute with no missing data in between this can be achieved very easily like so:

```
food.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        date: 1 // make sure the data is sorted by date
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        prices: { $push: "$price" }, // create an array per "name" with all prices in it
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        name: "$_id",
        price_last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$prices", -1 ] }, // select the first from the end of the array
        price_1m_ago:  { $arrayElemAt: [ "$prices", -2 ] }, // select the second from the end
        price_5m_ago:  { $arrayElemAt: [ "$prices", -6 ] } // select the 6th from the end
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately the time interval is random. Some times a have 2-3 prices in 1sec, some times only one in 1 minute. The prices write to DB on when the prises change on 3d-party server.

Comment: So what is the meaning of `1m_ago` and `5m_ago`? 1/5 minute(s) before the last available price update or 1 minute before the current date?

Comment: 1m_ago before the current date.

Answer (score 0):

I get this result, with @Avij first query. Here is some duplicates. And if i replace $minute:'$lastdate' with new Date(), the query not working.

```
{ _id: 'melon',
    lastPrice: 1575,
    five_min_price: 1573 },
  { _id: 'cherry',
    lastPrice: 60165,
    five_min_price: 59098 },
  { _id: 'apple',
    lastPrice: 0153,
    five_min_price: 0155 },
  { _id: 'apple',
    lastPrice: 0153,
    five_min_price: 0154 },
  { _id: 'apple',
    lastPrice: 0153,
    five_min_price: 0155 },
  { _id: 'apricot',
    lastPrice: 6897,
    five_min_price: 6235 },
  { _id: 'apricot',
    lastPrice: 6897,
    five_min_price: 6235 },
  { _id: 'apricot',
    lastPrice: 6897,
    five_min_price: 6822 },
  { _id: 'apricot',
    lastPrice: 6897,
    five_min_price: 683 },
  { _id: 'cucumber',
    lastPrice: 3461,
    five_min_price: 3533 },
  { _id: 'cucumber',
    lastPrice: 3461,
    five_min_price: 3496 },
  { _id: 'orange',
    lastPrice: 5366,
    five_min_price: 5367 }
```

Maybe the query can be cuted with $match, and then get last in this result. If the date in DB store in Unix format. This work for one result, but how i can get 10s/30s/1m/5m/10m/30m/1h results in one query.

```
var now = new Date();
var shift_5_min = shift_5_min = new Date( now.valueOf() - ( 5*60*1000 );

"$match": {
    "date": { "$lte": shift_5_min" }
}
$group: {
     id: "$name",
     price: {$last: "$price"}
}
```

Comment: are there "seconds" also in your time ? because here every where seconds are 0 in sample data, please check if in actual data seconds are also there?

Comment: do you want to track ONLY some time intervals or every other time interval?..also your Mongodb version please

Comment: Seconds also different. The full date store in DB is: ISODate(2018-01-04T14:14:47.290Z), with different s and ms.
I want to track the prices every 1sec. The data save to DB in different time period, from 1 to 5s for every product. And i want to track live prices on website using socket.io, and compare results by time interval. Let say the prices for apple change in 5% from last 10 minutes, and 7% from previous hour. @Avij

Comment: My MongoDB version is v3.6.0 @Avij

Comment: Any idea? @Avij